# Is there any way to kill session on closing browser? I have used the onunload and onbeforeunload event. but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, struts2

I have used the (window.onunload) and (window.onbeforeunload) event for capturing browser close event to kill session. but it doesn't work for me in chrome. Is there any way to do?

Comment: thanks for reply but idont know  about navigator.sendBeacon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal async `XMLHttpRequest` (including `fetch`) tend to be cancelled as the page closes. The usual workaround has been to make synchronous requests.

However, there's a new way to do it: [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). It was designed with pretty much that exact purpose in mind - it will queue a request to be executed even after the page is closed.

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/logout");
});
```

It still doesn't work on all browsers, so if you care about the lag-behinders you might want to test if it is available, and use the above-mentioned workaround if not.

Comment: Interesting; I had no idea this existed.