Angular @HostListener beforeunload Event
I have the following code in my "top-level" app.component.ts file in my Angular 17 project:
  @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
  onTabClose($event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {

    $event.preventDefault();
    // need to run logout() if user clicks "Leave"

  }

As the comment states, if the user decided to leave the page, I need to log the user out of the application (by calling a logout() ) method.
Is this event possible?

Yes, the beforeunload event is possible and can be used to perform actions before the user navigates away from the page or closes the browser window.

you might use sendBeacon() instead?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon  Just be sure you actually want to log them when closing a tab.  Also see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103472/is-there-any-way-to-kill-session-on-closing-browser-i-have-used-the-onunload-an

Once you give one of the actions there is no way to execute other methods or logic. Instead, execute the logout and then show alert, or do not logout at all.
This alert is great for handling the user exiting a form. We can prevent   their unsaved changes from being discarded, but not in this scenario.
